# Event Error - no price set found!

Tags: civievent

In the middle of entering registrants for an event and suddenly:

**No active price fields found for this event!**

This follows an update to 4.6.3 which has coughed up some DB errors. But up until this morning the event worked fine!

I have already tried flushing the cache to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Doh!**

The end date for the Price Set was set to today.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Don't forget to "accept" this answer to mark it as correct.